# What is wrong with this python 3 syntax for printing Conversion error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop

OK, I am following a great course on python on Pluralsight.  I'm stumped on this syntax error even though I'm staring right at the instructor's code that works fine.  It's real short.

```
import sys

def convert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        print("Conversion error: {}".format(str(e)), file=sys.stderr)
        return -1
```

The instructor used a \ after the error: {}"\ - that's how his code looked, with indents for the .format statement and the file= statement.  I've tried that along with a space after the quotation mark and the .format(str(e)) and I keep getting syntax errors when I import it into the REPL.  I'm using python 3.3, btw.
Thanks in advance for any tips,
Bruce

Comment: Can you include the exact text of the SyntaxError in your question? (Works for me on Python 3.2, so I'm kind of confused.)

Comment: This looks fine to me. If the `.format` was on a new line, the backslash was an explicit line continuation (and unnecessary, since it's in the middle of unclosed parentheses).

Comment: As a side note, the `{}` format already calls `str` on its arguments, so there is no reason to pass `str(e)`.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're not accidentally running Python 2.x? Because if you were, there would be a SyntaxError on exactly the line you mention (at the `=`), but in 3.3 there shouldn't be.

Comment: For me it's just working. I'm using python3.3 too. Note that if you're on windows that there's sometimes confusion about which python version is started.